# Overtime vs Pay Cut (California) (40-45 hours)

Tags: overtime, law, lunch, salaried-pay, hourly

I was under the impression that M-F 9am-5pm was 40 hours of work but my boss is now changing it to 8am-5pm which is 45 hours but at the same weekly rate.

What does California workplace laws say about this? Am I being taken advantage of? It's not like I can go home and eat lunch for that hour and because it's an office setting and I work on computers eating lunch at my desk while working is the norm.

I'm salaried if that matters.

Comment: Does your boss expect you to be in the office from 8am to 5pm? Or is it okay to have a one-hour lunch break?

Comment: https://www.shouselaw.com/employment/breaks.html

Comment: Are you an exempt employee?

Comment: What is your relationship with your boss?  Is it possible for you to ask him why the change, and expect a reasonable answer?

Comment: @BenBarden just that "we're a small business and we need to work more hours" kind of seems like a round about answer.

Comment: @spickermann 1x 30min lunch and 2x 15mins breaks neither is long enough for me to leave the office.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In California, your employer is [required to post](https://www.dir.ca.gov/wpnodb.html) the applicable labor laws.

One of the [required posters](https://www.dir.ca.gov/IWC/IWCArticle4.pdf) covers meal periods and rest breaks. You should be getting two paid breaks of at least 10 minutes, and one unpaid meal period of at least 30 minutes (but it's okay to require longer). The key here is that you can't be required to work during the meal period, otherwise it's paid.

It doesn't matter if you don't want an hour meal period, your employer can make that part of the schedule. What they can't do is lump your other two breaks in, and they can't ask you to work during any of those -- even "just answer the phone if it rings" is a no-no.

Answer (score 1):

First, I will say that this is not the place to go for matters of law.  We are not lawyers here.  My *guess* is that this is legal, as I'll explain further on, but I'll tell you with certainty that you don't want to pursue a legal solution.  The hours thing here is relatively minor, and the only thing you could possibly win would be a marginally improved situation with work hours.  At the same time, the only tools you could reasonably wield here would be legal action or threat of same, and that sort of thing will absolutely poison your relationship with your employer.  The minimal time you *might* gain from it is not worth the relationship damage you absolutely *would* inflict upon yourself.

Second, you're salaried.  That means... basically, it means you work when you work.  I don't know California law, but in general, there are very few laws protecting salaried individuals with respect to hours.  There' a lot of places where 9 hours per day would be considered tame.  The real question then is if you are willing to work the hours demanded for the pay offered.  If you're not?  Stick it out for long enough to get yourself a job that will give you what you actually want from a job.

In my experience, half an hour is enough time to dash out to a nearby restaurant to eat, or at least to take your lunch outside of the building.  If he's counting that half an hour as mandatory "you have to take this time, it doesn't count as working time" then you absolutely should not be taking it as a working lunch at your desk.  If he's telling you to take breaks, then take actual breaks.  Sure, it's not enough time to get home or something, but that's not the point.  The point is to give yourself a brief mental break.

Regardless, nine hours, minus half an hour for lunch and two 15-minute breaks *is* 8 hours per day.  In general, your boss may be being a bit autocratic about exactly how much time must be spent on each thing.  (How flexible is your lunch break length?  Does it have to be *exactly* 30 minutes?)  Beyond that, though, this is not particularly unreasonable, compared to what else is out there.

Comment: In California, you get two paid 10-minute breaks in an 8 hour day. This means the lunch should be an hour, and if it's not paid then OP should be free (even encouraged) to step away from the desk for that time.

Comment: If something has changed with what the manager desires with regards to your hours I suspect there might be more to it. You should ask the manager what has changed.  This is a question you should ask yourself, "am I working for 8 hours every day?" if the answer to that question isn't "Yes" then you might have identified a potential problem.

Comment: @Kathy That's true only for non-exempt employees. I work in California in an exempt job and my employer doesn't make me take a lunch break or 10-minute breaks.

Comment: @mkennedy Of course if you're an exempt employee there's no difference between paid and unpaid time. :) But if your employer doesn't encourage you to take a break regularly, they are the ones losing out. So many studies show people are more productive when they step away from the desk now and then.